# Qt doesn't recognize existance of files inside .qrc

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

**UPDATE:**
I get the following from file.errorString: "Unknown error" ... helpful. Also my .pro file source:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = RegionsBuilder2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += style.qrc
```

And my .qrc file source:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/qss_icons">
        <file>rc/up_arrow_disabled.png</file>
        <file>rc/Hmovetoolbar.png</file>
        <file>rc/stylesheet-branch-end.png</file>
        <file>rc/branch_closed-on.png</file>
        <file>rc/stylesheet-vline.png</file>
        <file>rc/branch_closed.png</file>
        <file>rc/branch_open-on.png</file>
        <file>rc/transparent.png</file>
        <file>rc/right_arrow_disabled.png</file>
        <file>rc/sizegrip.png</file>
        <file>rc/close.png</file>
        <file>rc/down_arrow.png</file>
        <file>rc/Vmovetoolbar.png</file>
        <file>rc/left_arrow.png</file>
        <file>rc/stylesheet-branch-more.png</file>
        <file>rc/up_arrow.png</file>
        <file>rc/right_arrow.png</file>
        <file>rc/left_arrow_disabled.png</file>
        <file>rc/Hsepartoolbar.png</file>
        <file>rc/checkbox.png</file>
        <file>rc/branch_open.png</file>
        <file>rc/Vsepartoolbar.png</file>
        <file>rc/down_arrow_disabled.png</file>
        <file>rc/undock.png</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/qdarkstyle">
        <file>style.qss</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/misc">
        <file>cman.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**ORIGINAL:**

I'm new to Qt 5.2.1 (and in general) and am using Qt Creator to build a desktop application. I'm trying to use an external style sheet, so I did some reading online, found a good free style sheet, and read up on how to load it into my code as a resource. My issue is with the resource files, I created a resource as I read I was supposed to and tried to open it in my main function to apply the stylesheet. Qt doesn't seem to think the file exists, Qt Creator certainly recognizes the correct placement and existence of all these files within the resource, but file.open returns false every time. Here are some shots:

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

[image: screen3]

[image: screen4]

Comment: What does file.errorString() return in the else branch? Add the source of your .pro file and .qrc file (instead of screenshots).

Comment: I think originally I was trying to make sure I didn't miss anything important the first time, but got it.

Comment: @ChristopherBrown: did you re-run qmake? What does file.errorString() say as Frank requested?

Comment: You can try deleting all generated build files including the make files are rebuild your project.

Comment: I added the errorString in the post update. @Nejat will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! All that was required was a quick call to "clean." Thanks @Nejat for the tip!